# Kendo.ParseDate throws syntax error when trying to format date in template

Tags: html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

This is probably a simple problem to fix, but I am at the end of my patience trying to find to a solution. I am using a kendo ui inline grid, and I have two date fields. The values themselves seem to come through as strings, which i was able to solve by use of the oode below.

```
        <div id="Grid" class="inline-edit-grid"
             <!-- ... -->
             data-columns="[
             <!-- ... -->
                { field: 'RequestedDate',title: 'Requested', width: 15, template: '#= kendo.parseDate(RequestedDate,'M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt')#'},
                { field: 'AcceptedDate',title: 'Accepted', width: 15, template: '#= kendo.parseDate(AcceptedDate,'M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt')#'},
              ]">
```

This works to give me a date value, however it is in the format "Thu Nov 09 2017 13:15:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)". Instead I would like to have the format in 'M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt'. Hence I tried to use the code

```
 { field: 'RequestedDate',title: 'Requested', width: 15, template: '#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(RequestedDate,'M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt'))#'}
```

Which throws a syntax error at the format string. By all accounts this shouldn't be happening, and I have tried plenty of combinations of format strings at this point to the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the use of quotes within the quoted string for the template. You can see the problem by the way the string below is colored:

```
'#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(RequestedDate,'M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt'))#'
```

You can try using double quotes to enclose the string with single quotes within:

```
"#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(RequestedDate,'M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt'))#"
```

Or vice versa:

```
'#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(RequestedDate,"M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt"))#'
```

Or escape the quotes inside the string with \. You might need double \\ to escape, I can't remember:

```
'#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(RequestedDate,\'M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt\'))#'
```

One or all of those should work.

Okay, try this:

```
template: '#= kendo.toString(new Date(RequestedDate), "G")#',
```

You don't need to parse the date, instead create a javascript date from it and then format it with kendo.toString.
Check here https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/dateformatting for formatting options.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I've already tried switching to double quotes. For some reason this results in forward slashes being interpreted as ending the div. Alternatively putting the double quotes on the outside of the of the # symbols causes numerous other errors. The escape actually had the interesting result of causing the values to be returned as null, and double escapes caused numerous errors. This may be an issue in the way the data-columns themselves are created?

Comment: Please see above for a solution. I tested this in a dojo and believe it's the right approach.

Comment: There must be something else going on because this solution resulted in a solid wall of red error messages, when I used the double quotations. When I used the single quotations i get a single syntax error back.

Comment: So I was able to get the last solution working once i separated the template out to its own <script> section. The double quotes for the data-columns parameter prevent the double quotes in an inline template. When the template references a text/x-kendo-template script then the double quotes are able to be used, and the whole thing works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong quotation marks.

Change to

```
'#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(RequestedDate,"M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt"))#'
```

should fix the error.

Hope this is helpful for you :)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I've already tried switching to double quotes. For some reason this results in forward slashes being interpreted as ending the div.